# In use HttpService is not an WebContainer (from Pax Web)

Tags: java, session, jax-rs, osgi, whiteboard

I'm trying to get SessionListener work with my JAX-RS JSON channel. A bit probing in the dark, I was trying to instantiate Pax-Whiteboard environment which ought to be able to process the listener, so I've added the bundles to my OSGi environment. Now I have the following error:

> [Blueprint Extender: 3] ERROR
>   org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.whiteboard.internal.WebApplication -
>   Registration skipped for
>   [ListenerWebElement{mapping=DefaultListenerMapping{httpContextId=null,listener=org.example.MySessionListener@5c235feb}}]
>   due to error during registration
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Internal error: In use
>   HttpService is not an WebContainer (from Pax Web)

What does this error mean? Does it mean, that Pax-processed SessionListener can't be used because Pax creates own HttpService, and I already have those that supports JAX-WS?

And more specifically, is there a way I can deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some Pax-Web bundles. 
The OSGi HttpService Spec doesn't provide the possibility for SessionListeners, this is only possible with the new OSGi R6 Http Whiteboard specification. 
Depending on the version of Pax-Web you're using, this is possible or not possible. 
But to have this, especially for versions prior 6.0, you'll also need to add the Pax-Web-War and maybe some more bundle to your environment. 
Take a look at the corresponding integration tests of the Pax-Web project
[Pax-Web-Integrationtests base class](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/ITestBase.java#L59-L85)
This is a complete list of bundles needed to run Pax-Web including with War extensions, so you  might need to strip of some.